# Compared to Ruby, in Javascript, when iterating through an array, do you not need to "protect" against going out of bounds with the iterator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, iterator

Maybe my array-fu is not quite up to snuff in Ruby, but I find myself always feeling the need to protect against a modified iterator value going "out of bounds" of the array length.

I just looked at some code in Javascript and it seems like its author didn't feel the need to do these same "checks".

Which got me wondering, do I need to do these checks in Ruby? Is the problem, perhaps, how I'm going about iterating through an array?

For example, in Ruby, in order to prevent a "-1" iterator from pulling in the last array value (ie `array[-1]`) or going beyond the array's length (thus returning `nil`), I find myself doing the following:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.each_index do |i|
  unless i == 0 
    previous_value = array[i - 1]
    ...

  unless array[i + 1] == nil
    ...
end
```

Whereas in the Javascript solution, it just went right along without a care in the world about an "out of bounds" iterator value:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) if(array[i] <= array[i - 1]) {
  ...
  if array[i+1] 
    ...
}
```

Is there a way in Ruby to let the iterator be "smart enough" to not need me to hold its hand regarding values outside of `0..array.length-1`, similar to that shown in Javascript?

Comment: The JS does care about the "out of bounds" value, kinda - it'll give you `undefined` if you mess up the `for` loop declaration and change the indicies being iterated over. (though, it won't throw)

Comment: Hello @CertainPerformance! Interesting... So does Ruby need to have the out-of-bounds modified iterators explicitly "caged" in conditionals? Or is there a better way to handle iterators?

Comment: Also you're perhaps too liberal in labeling things as iterators. Iterators proper (`each` / `each_index` and their relatives) won't go out of bounds. But if you're modifying the index and using it in the indexer, then all warranties are voided, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to process pairs of elements. if that's the case, ruby has a better method.

```
[1,2,3,4].each_cons(2) do |value1, value2|
  p [value1, value2]
end
# >> [1, 2]
# >> [2, 3]
# >> [3, 4]
```

Or you can iterate from the second index until second to last.

```
1.upto(array.size-2) do |i|
  value = array[i]
  previous_value = array[i-1]
  next_value = array[i+1]
  ...
end
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you @Sergio_Tulentsev! Those two approaches will help a LOT!